# Runaway usercards on non-responsive pages

Tags: bug, design, revisions-list, user-card

On any site, when browsing non responsive pages such as  the [revisions page](https://meta.stackexchange.com/posts/9182/revisions) or [the review queue](https://stackoverflow.com/review/close/21661313) (see proposed duplicate for expandable usercards) in a narrower browser window, the expanded profile card absconds:

> [image: Jon Skeet can run fast even when he's sitting down!]

Are these pages going to be responsive?

I'm using Chrome on Mac.